# Exclude underlying objects when storing data using EF6

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have a class Ticket which has some properties. Three of these (View, Task and Key) properties are navigation properties. Those properties already exist in database even before a ticket has been stored. In my application I load those properties from the database first and then create a Ticket object. I need to save only the ticket (not the underlying objects ) to the database with the id to Key, View and Task (these are primery keys in the Ticket table)

```
[Table("Tickets")]
public class Ticket
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Created { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public View View{ get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Key Key { get; set; }

    public Task Task { get; set; }


}
```

I try to save the Ticket object like this:

```
        db.Tickets.Add(ticket);
        db.Entry(ticket.Key).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged;
        db.Entry(ticket.View).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged;
        db.Entry(ticket.Task).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged;

db.SaveChanges();
```

When I try this approach I get the error:

```
{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Saving or accepting changes failed because more than one entity of type 'Key' have the same primary key value. Ensure that explicitly set primary key values are unique. Ensure that database-generated primary keys are configured correctly in the database and in the Entity Framework model. Use the Entity Designer for Database First/Model First configuration. Use the 'HasDatabaseGeneratedOption\" fluent API or 'DatabaseGeneratedAttribute' for Code First configuration.","
```

Is it even possible to work with Entity Framework this way? Having pre defined data which is loaded to it's objects (Key, View, Task) first and later assign these objects to an object having these properties but then in the entity framework context only adding the parent object, in this case the ticket?

I have also tried to set the underlying objects to null but then I will loose the data for those underlying objects, data I need later on in the application.
This is how the underlying objects look like:

```
    [Table("Views")]
public class View
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Version { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime? Created { get; set; }
}

    [Table("Keys")]
public class Key
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Version { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime? Created { get; set; }
}

    [Table("Tasks")]
public class Task
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Version { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime? Created { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Did you try the `EntityState.Detached`?

Comment: Detached will set the underlying objects to null, I need those objects later on in the application.

Comment: One interesting question: do you actually need these navigation properties? We don't use them at all in applications.

Comment: Yes, I need the View-, Key- and Task object throughout a request. Once a Request is made I create these objects for validation purposes then when everything is OK i create a Ticket, this ticket with the properties is used later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding Foreign Keys to your object and making those required instead of making the navigation property required. Like so:

```
[Table("Tickets")]
public class Ticket
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Created { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ViewId {get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ViewId")]
    public View View{ get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int KeyId {get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("KeyId")]
    public Key Key { get; set; }

    public Task Task { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: if I look in the database there already is foreing keys for e.g Key is an int in Tickets table Key_Id(FK, int, not null)

Comment: Ok, if you change the property name to match the database naming convention it should work fine. So change KeyId to Key_Id

Comment: But why should I add the ForeignKey attribute? The navigation properties is ForeignKey by default when code first generates the database with my current code? Thanks

Comment: You want to add it so that all you have to do is set the FK value and not set the whole navigation property when you save.

Comment: I will try it out, thanks. I will get back to you if it works.

Comment: I am about to test it out but what if I must allow that multiple Tickets can have the same Task? One scenario is when different view and key have the same Task?

Comment: That's completely fine. You can have two different objects reference the same shared object. Just set the same FK on each of the two objects.

Comment: Thank you, it works a lot better with this approach.